# Foreverjs tries to find module in /node_modules/my-module/node_modules/my-module

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, forever

I use [foreverjs](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever/) to start my services. Also I use **nodejs v5** with [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). Running on mac.

Everything **working fine yesterday**, but today (after `npm update`) I suddenly have an errors like `/node_modules/my-service-one/node_modules/my-service-one`when I'm try to `npm start`.

The project structure is:

```
 .
 |-package.json
 |-services.json
 |+-node_modules
   |-forever
   |-my-service-one
   |-my-service-two
```

Config for foreverjs (`services.json`):

```
[
  {
    "append": true,
    "uid": "my-service-one",
    "script": "index.js",
    "sourceDir": "node_modules/my-service-one"
  },
  {
    "append": true,
    "uid": "my-service-two",
    "script": "index.js",
    "sourceDir": "node_modules/my-service-two"
  }
]
```

And I launch it with npm start(`package.json`):

```
...
"scripts": {
  "start": "node_modules/forever/bin/forever start services.json",
}
...
```

But when I try to make `npm start`, I have an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/my_user/project_name/node_modules/my-service-one/node_modules/my-service-one/index.js'
```

---

**WTF is this**: `/node_modules/my-service-one/node_modules/my-service-one`? Why?
It should use `/node_modules/my-service-one/index.js`. So why?

---

**UPD**: What I've already try(without result):

- `rm -rf node_modules`;
- Restart;
- Use node v4, v5, v6;
- `npm cache clean`;
- Find other `node_modules` in wrong places inside project;
- Google it;

This is bad question perhaps, but I'm really didn't know why it's happens. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to launch this modules with forever from command line?

This path issue looks like a bug for me, I think the obvious duct-tape type fix is use absolute path in `services.json` instead of relative. It will look terrible but it should work.

But I think it's better to install `forever` globally (with `-g` key) and then use a simple shell script to start your services with forever (two lines with something `forever start /Users/my_user/project_name/node_modules/my-service-one/index.js`) - this way works fine for me.

And also it's quite easy to start this script at the boot-up, or even write a script to start and stop your modules as a service.

---

**UPD:** This also may helps: `sourceDir: './'`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is work for me. A bit hacky but better than nothing. To be honest I don't like to accept a hacky-way answers but I'll accept your answer if nobody will offer a better one in a couple of days

Comment: Solution with forever in shell script works for me perfectly already with 3 different servers for more than 1 year, so I would recommend it. And it's quite convenient to have node thread as a simple normal service (more useful for unix servers of course).